# Can't add a shortcut with Alt using PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

I've formatted my PC (Windows) and Installed PhpStorm v2017.2.2 and I'm having troubles adding/using some of the shortcuts that are made by pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

For example, The default shortcut to toggle the terminal is <kbd>Alt + F12</kbd>. When I press on these keys, nothing happens.

When I try to re-assign the shortcut, PhpStorm ignores the keypress of <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Same when I try to toggle the *Version Control* using the shortcut <kbd>Alt + 9</kbd>.

When I press only on <kbd>Alt</kbd>, PhpStorm shows some menus, which indicates that my <kbd>Alt</kbd> is fine.

I've tried pressing on the second <kbd>Alt</kbd> button - but still no luck.

Comment: Try latest stable **2017.2.4**. What keyboard layout/input language do you have there? try with English .. and make sure it's "standard" layout (not Dvorak or alike). As I understand IDE is unable to register `Alt` presses (in `Setting | Keymap` there is a button next to search field that allows to fins actions by assigned shortcuts -- see if it will locate any / will recognize Alt press there). So far it sounds like it's your OS settings somewhere... BTW -- does it work OK in other apps?

Comment: I've updated to 2017.2.4 version and I'm using a standard layout. It looks like I can press the Alt button with other buttons as long as the other key isn't a number [0-9] or an F [F1-F12] keys. If it's an OS issue, Do you might know what can cause this?

Comment: Does it work in other apps? If not -- maybe you have an app that intercepts them (e.g. some messenger or another always-run-in-background app). Try exiting all apps from your tray (one by one checking if IDE recognize key after each of them). If other apps can accept such shortcuts just fine -- maybe some custom plugin that you have installed? No other ideas at the moment. Maybe look for some Key Press monitor/Investigator kind of app that would tell more details (I've read about them from other users .. but do not remember the name, at all).

Comment: BTW -- what about your keyboard (an actual hardware keyboard)? Is that a laptop or some small-form one? Maybe it has "Fn" or alike key there (can be seen on laptops) that would have different functionality to Fx keys (but then .. numbers should be unaffected I believe). No other ideas.

Comment: I have tried using Alt+1 on this website http://www.keyboardtester.com/tester.html and it looks ok. My keyboard is called "Ryos MK". It's not a small form thingy. I've already tried with or without the Fn button but it still didn't work.

Comment: If you go to File | Settings | Keymap > "find action by shortcut" button on upper right - would it show `Alt` if you try to search for e.g. `alt+1` or `alt+f12`?